# Disable creation of .bak files

Tags: asp.net, iis

How can I disable the creation of .bak files in IIS?
We have a website in our production server and inside my app_Files folder I have a bunch of aspx pages and code files (web forms).  Sometimes I see a bunch of .bak files in there as well.  I am not sure whats triggering them to be created.  Is it possible to disable them being created?  Whats the purpose of them being created in the production server?

Comment: "I am not sure whats triggering them to be created." Clearly not Windows/IIS/ASP.NET. Track down the source (such as the code of the web apps) and then you can find a fix.

Comment: you're saying there is a code somewhere in the application that's triggering them to be created manually?